# Proof of $P(A|B)=1−P(A^{c}|B)$

Tags: probability

I see that there is a "fact" $P(A|B)=1−P(A^{c}|B))$, this can be deduced or what is the intuition? I can see that the "domain" is reduced in both cases to $B$ and that we use $A$ and $A^{c}$ and this makes sense I just don't know where to take this "fact" from.

Comment: Your understanding sounds right to me. Basically, in any "domain", the probabilities of complementary events must sum up to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A^\complement\mid B) ={}& \dfrac{\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B)}{\mathsf P(B)}&&\text{by definition of conditional probability}\\[1ex] ={}& \dfrac{\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)}{\mathsf P(B)} && \raise{2ex}{\text{via the Law for Total Probability}\\{\small \mathsf P(B)=\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B)}} \\[1ex]={}& 1-\mathsf P(A\mid B)&&\text{by definition of conditional probability}\end{align}$$

That is all.